# cannot override react-table styles?

Tags: css, react-table

From the docs of [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) it is stated that:

> We think the default styles looks great! But, if you prefer a more custom look, all of the included styles are easily overridable. Every single component contains a unique class that makes it super easy to customize. Just go for it!

I tried overriding a className of `.ReactTable .-pagination .-pageSizeOptions` as seen here: [image]

```
.ReactTable .-pagination .-pageSizeOptions {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 3px 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But it has no effect? but if i do that on inspect element, it's working, I am importing my overrides on the root index.js, tried it on the file, no effetct.

```
require('./react-table-overrides.css');

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Help?

Comment: Is this file in memory `react-table-overrides.css` before inspecting ?

Comment: @rach8garg i imported it on public/index.html, I have problems importing it in node :/

Answer (score 2):

Try using css modules and :global, it's works for me

```
:global div.pagination-bottom > div > div.-center > span.select-wrap.-pageSizeOptions {
  visibility: hidden !important;
  margin: 3px 10px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}
```